# Converting multiple .txt files in a folder to shapefile

Tags: arcpy

I want to convert my .txt files to shapefile. I want the system to be able to move to the next .txt file in the folder, other than me inputting one after the other. This is what I have done but I have to input the files one after the other which takes a lot of time

```
 import arcpy

 newfcName ="532724.shp"
 outpath = r"C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE"

# Declaration
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace= outpath


# Create new Shapefile and add FIELDS
newfc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfcName, "Point")
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "X", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Y", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Z", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "I", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)

# Reference Cursors
cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, [ "SHAPE@XY", "X", "Y", "Z", "I"])

# Read File 
a = open("C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE/DEM/532724.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()

for line in inputF:
xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue, iValue = line.split(" ")
xy = (float(xCoordinate), float(yCoordinate))
newRow = (xy, str(xCoordinate), str(yCoordinate), str(zValue), float(iValue))
cursor.insertRow(newRow)

a.close()
infc = r"C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE/532724.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("Minna UTM Zone 31N")
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(infc, sr)
```

Comment: Shapefile name should not start with numbers. Please refer to this question regarding naming convention: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7886/is-starting-names-with-numbers-a-bad-data-naming-convention

Comment: indent the contents of the 'for' loop.  Most other languages indenting inside a loop is a convention, but with python, it's required.

Comment: Are you interested in merging the contents of multiple TXT file into a single shape file or do you want each TXT file to become its own, new shape file?  If the latter, do you want the shape file to have the same name as the text file?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over the files in the directory.

See the code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory