# Adding shapefile name as attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, merge

I have 397 shapefiles that I need to merge into one shapefile, and I need to add an attribute for the name of each of the shapefiles. I have no experience in coding/ Python.

Is this possible to do without any coding in ArcMap 10.3?

Comment: What do you mean by attribute for the name?

Comment: @User2009 The file names are 1.shp, 2.shp, etc and I want the 1, 2, etc to be in the attribute column.

Comment: @cm1I had a look at that, but it requires some coding. I have no experience in coding sadly.

Comment: Shapefiles cannot start with numbers.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I think you're thinking of geodatabase feature classes, shapefiles are just regular file system files and can start with numbers or any other character permitted by the file system.

Comment: @DanC thanks for the information. Starting a shapefile name with numbers can cause an error as far as I know. This was also discussed here in this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7886/is-starting-names-with-numbers-a-bad-data-naming-convention

Comment: @MaitriShah You can edit your question by using ModelBuilder. so you can add the name filed for each shapefile and merge all of them