# Open-source software for managing terabytes of different formats of geospatial data?

Tags: qgis, postgis, open-source-gis, data-management

I have a problem that I am sure many GIS Teams or Departments have which is how to find, keep track of and manage multiple different datasets from multiple sources. I have read the responses from a similar question asked two years ago

[Managing large amounts of geospatial data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/721/best-practices-for-managing-geospatial-data)

I was wondering if there are any other software solutions, I know about VoyagerGIS, which looks good, but it is linked with ESRI and wondered if there was a similar Open Source version.

To give you an overview of the current situation:

1. Terabytes of Imagery which changes every 6 weeks, I would like to keep historic
2. 1 Terabyte of MapInfo TABs
3. ESRI Shapefiles again changes every 6 weeks
4. 100s Gbs of CSV, GeoJSON, KML, SQLite, Excel spreadsheets, JPEGs, TIF files (some georeferenced, some with world files), these come in from multiple different sources.

I guess my perfect solution would be a GUI interface to allow me to update metadata, search based on filename or even attribute, a visual image (like seen in VoyagerGIS), it show metadata, a list of attributes. However, I would like to keep the original format of the data rather than loading it all into PostGIS.

Comment: Have you looked at the meta data plug in for QGIS? Can you comment on that?

Comment: Probably not covering all of your needs, but perhaps a look at a CSW tool like http://geonetwork-opensource.org/ may help solve part of the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about [QGIS Browser](http://www.qgis.org/about-qgis/features.html#browser)?

[image]

> QGIS trunk now comes with a separate tool called “QGIS Browser”. It
>   enables the user to browse through all spatial data files on the
>   system as well as all WMS configured in QGIS. Both files and WMS
>   layers are listed in a tree widget on the left side while metadata,
>   attributes and a preview can be seen on the right.

Though I'm not so sure about your search requirement.

You can couple this with the [Metatools plugin](http://nextgis.ru/en/blog/metatools/).

> Metatools provides convenient interface for creating, editing and
>   viewing metadata. There is batch mode for processing large amount of
>   data, templates support to simplify some editing operations, also
>   there is a possibility to extract some information (such as extent,
>   bands number, data type…) automatically and option for preview
>   generation.

[image]

Comment: Hi All Thanks for the replies, I get the feeling it is not a one stop solution. I think I will look in QGIS Browser first and compare against VoyagerGIS.